# Getting error while compiling in keil?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker, usb, keil

I am working with MK60N512MD100 (TWR-K60N512 tower kit) I am trying to extract Freescale_USB_Stack_v4.1.1 and creating my own project, But I am getting following error even after I copied all related files.

***********************error LOG ************************

```
> main_kinetis.c: 5 warnings, 0 errors linking... .\USB_DEV.axf:
> Warning: L6304W: Duplicate input file .\startup_mk60n512md100.o
> ignored. .\USB_DEV.axf: Error: L6320W: Ignoring --entry command.
> Cannot find argument 'Reset_Handler'. .\USB_DEV.axf: Warning: L6320W:
> Ignoring --first command. Cannot find argument '__Vectors'. Not enough
> information to list image symbols. Not enough information to list the
> image map. Finished: 2 information, 2 warning and 1 error messages.
> ".\USB_DEV.axf" - 1 Error(s), 7 Warning(s). Target not created
```

---

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Make sure you have only one file in your project which is called `startup_mk60n512md100.s` and this (assembly) file contains the symbols for `Reset_Handler` and `__Vectors` which are necessary for the linker to create the executable image file.

Comment: Thank for your valuable reply . I have startup_mk60512md100.s file in my projec